# WSO2 MySQL Adaptor Sytax Error

Tags: mysql, wso2

I am trying to create an event formatter for MySql in WSO2 but am hitting a problem. It appears to be linked to the use of "Composite Key Columns". The error I am getting is:

> ERROR - {MysqlEventAdaptorType}
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Window = '15'' at line 1

This only happens if I use a two or more keys in the formatter:

```
<eventFormatter name="GenericAccountSQLFormatter" statistics="enable"
  trace="enable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventformatter">
  <from streamName="GenericAccountMeasureStream" version="1.0.0"/>
  <mapping customMapping="disable" type="map"/>
  <to eventAdaptorName="APCSQLOut" eventAdaptorType="mysql">
    <property name="table.name">AccountStats</property>
    <property name="update.keys">AccountId,Window</property>
    <property name="execution.mode">insert-or-update</property>
  </to>
</eventFormatter>
```

Removing either of the keys (AccountId, Window) then the formatter will send data to MySQL.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and happens when existing events are sent to a MySQL adaptor with composite keys. Created a [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-900) to track this and the source patch is also available there.

If you don't want to create/apply a patch, then as a quick workaround for now - you can output a composite key from CEP query by concatenating the two attributes and use that as the key in formatter.

**UPDATE**

The source patch with the fix and build instructions are now available in the [jira here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-900). Once built, you need to apply it as a patch to CEP. To apply it as a patch, create a directory named patch0xyz ( xyz are digits as in patch0135, also make xyz > 100) in `<CEP>/repository/components/patches` and then place the jar inside it. Then you need to rename the jar as `org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adaptor.mysql_1.0.1.jar`. Then restart the server.